# What is the most common way to integrate reports into a .Net web application?

Tags: reporting-services

The following are the 3 ways that I know and would like to know the experiences from SO users.

- URL-based
- Report Viewer Control from Visual Studio
- Web Services

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're using as a report *generator* on the server side, but I've found that serving up reports in PDF format is a relatively pain-free, cross-platform way to go.  Almost everybody has Adobe Reader installed.

**Update**: sorry, I missed the SSRS tags, but you can output SSRS reports to PDF:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/PDFUsingSQLRepServices.aspx

I still recommend PDF for the delivered report format.  Cross-browser and near-universal, two things that make me (and clients) very happy.

Comment: @MusiGenesis, What do you use as a Report Generator/PDF Creator?

Comment: @Robert: ActiveReports (but it's been a couple of years).

Comment: Wouldn't the report generator be SSRS? That's what the question is tagged with.

Comment: @JPot: I didn't even notice the tags. Sorry, thought this was a more general question.